# How to get last X records of the modsec_audit.log file?

Tags: shell, sed, tail, mod-security, mod-security2

I need to get the last X records of the modsec_audit.log file in bash and write it out to a new file. I know this is possible with tail and sed, but this possibly cuts out at a certain line and causes half of a message to be left in the beginning.
Is there a cleaner way to do this? I just need to get the X last events/items from the log file.

For those not familiar with modsecurity log files, here is an example of the modsec_audit.log file:

```
--38321e0f-E--
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>503 Service Unavailable</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Service Unavailable</h1>
<p>The server is temporarily unable to service your
request due to maintenance downtime or capacity
problems. Please try again later.</p>
<hr>
<address>Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) Server at 10.211.55.6 Port 80</address>
</body></html>

--38321e0f-H--
Message: Access denied with code 503 (phase 2). Pattern match "block_hack" at ARGS:block_hack. [file "/usr/share/modsecurity-crs/activated_rules/block_hack.conf"] [line "2"] [id "11212"]
Action: Intercepted (phase 2)
Apache-Handler: application/x-httpd-php
Stopwatch: 1443442449908332 455 (- - -)
Stopwatch2: 1443442449908332 455; combined=23, p1=6, p2=15, p3=0, p4=0, p5=2, sr=0, sw=0, l=0, gc=0
Response-Body-Transformed: Dechunked
Producer: ModSecurity for Apache/2.7.7 (http://www.modsecurity.org/).
Server: Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu)
Engine-Mode: "ENABLED"

--38321e0f-Z--
```

Comment: Why do you need this? The Apache error file will have the details of any error on one line which is often easier to deal with than trying to deal with the multi-line audit log.

Comment: I am making a Modsecurity specific application. Thus I need to get access to the last X records of the modsecurity file. I know the apache has also usefull info, but I need to focus here on modsec_audit.log

Comment: Ok. Just thought I'd mention in case you didn't know that ModSecurity also logs to Apache error file in a more easily grep-able format. But it doesn't have as much info as audit log.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

some hacking with awk and tac

start with generous tail, reverse, print top 3 records, reverse

```
tail -100 log2 | tac | awk -vRS= -vORS="\n\n" 'NR<4' | tac
```

will print the last 3 records from the original log.

**Explanation:**

Since the log file can be very large you may want to limit the operation on the last few lines. If your records are 10 lines long, `tail` a corresponding section that will include at least n*10 lines.  As most other tools `awk` start from the beginning of the file, that's why we reverse the lines with `tac` print n records and reverse back to the original format.

`RS=` sets awk to paragraph mode (records separated one or more empty lines), similarly `ORS="\n\n"` for printing records separated by an empty line.  `NR<4` condition will be true for records 1,2,3 and will be printed (as the default action of `awk`). `-v` is the optional tag to define variables.

Comment: Thanks this works! But it shows top 2 records in my case (which is not a problem, just a sidenote).

Comment: could you please explain "tail -100", and "awk -vRS= -vORS="\n\n" 'NR<4' | tac"

Comment: please see the update. If you have 2 records printed perhaps 100 lines are not enough.

Comment: if I change 'NR<4' to 'NR<5' i got 12 records, if I use 'NR<6' i got arround 16 records. Any idea how to a linear scale?

Comment: it's counting paragraphs separated by an empty line.  Are you sure all your records are in the same format as you posted above?

Comment: It does work after all. I increased the tail length and now it's working!! Big thanks and thanks for the explanation and patience.

Answer (score 0):

Another option might be like this... `grep` for all the `--` at the start of the lines and number them like this:

```
grep -n "^--" modsec_audit.log
```

**Sample output**

```
1:--38321e0f-E--
14:--38321e0f-H--
25:--38321e0f-Z--
26:--38321e0f-E--
39:--38321e0f-H--
50:--38321e0f-Z--
51:--38321e0f-E--  <--- 51 is the line number of the 3rd last one
64:--38321e0f-H--
75:--38321e0f-Z--
```

So now delete (i.e. suppress printing) lines 1-50 of the file:

```
sed '1,50d' modsec_audit.log
```